# Current status of automatic parallelism in Haskell

Tags: optimization, haskell, parallel-processing, multicore, ghc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the status of multicore programming in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063652/whats-the-status-of-multicore-programming-in-haskell)

What is the status especially in GHC? Is it popular yet, or still being experimental?

How careful/fine-grained is the compiler in deciding when and how to parallelize? Does the run-time choose the threadpool's size appropriately or we have to specify through command line?

Comment: Gee who just downvoted me? I lost 2 reps!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GHC's current scheduling, thread pool and migration policies are described in the paper "[Runtime Support for Multicore Haskell](http://ghcmutterings.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/new-paper-runtime-support-for-multicore-haskell/)". The "strategies" style *semi*-automatic parallelism is quite widely used, at the time of writing.

Answer (score 5):

The long answer is the paper linked in Don's response.  The short answer:

1. GHC does not automatically parallelise your program.
2. However, it makes it very easy to introduce parallelism via the [`par`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.1.0.1/doc/html/Control-Parallel.html) combinator.  The higher-level interface to this are the ["strategies"](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.1.0.1/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html) Don mentioned.
3. Whether simply adding `par` will speed up your program depends very much on your algorithm.  The upside is, there are no gotchas -- you can't introduce deadlocks or races (unless you're cheating the type system).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps by "automatic parallelism" you meant [Data Parallel Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell)? As far as I have seen the most current information about this project is available in [a video presentation by Simon Peyton Jones](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWSZ4c9yqW8), from April 2010.