# Haskell, FFI, and Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: haskell, multicore, ghc, grand-central-dispatch, ffi

I'm considering a functional language that will play well with my environment of C/Objective-C under FreeBSD, OSX, iOS.  It looks like my best bet is to create functional-language libraries for specific functions, written in Haskell, compile with GHC, and use FFI to call this functional code as a standard C call.

My question is, how do I handle concurrency in this situation?  **One** motivation for using a functional language is that for my problems where I want to operate on immutable datasets, I want to get a lot of parallelization going.  However, using the approach I detail here, will I get ANY parallelization?  It appears I can compile and dictate to use 2 threads, but is there any way to use GCD instead of threading (for all the reasons GCD is better than threads, such as the amount of parallelization automatically scaling per-platform)?  Or, going with FFI as I describe, do I completely lose the ability to multithread?

This language seems like the best match for what I'm trying to do, but I want to learn if it's the right fit before I devote a significant amount of time to truly learn it

Comment: You might have a look at Erlang for parallel and distributed functional programming.

Comment: You need to spell out lots more details -- what sorts of apps are you developing? What sorts of functions are you hoping to write in Haskell vs. C? What level of parallelism do you want to exploit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GHC's runtime replaces the need for GCD, doesn't it? And it already provides cross-platform parallelism.

Comment: Does it?  How exactly?  What is this called so that I can find more information about it?  And when I'm using the fully compiled and statically linked w/runtime GHC output in my code, does this parallelism happen without any intervention on my part?

Comment: GHC provides a rich runtime system supporting [many parallel and concurrent programming models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063652/whats-the-status-of-multicore-programming-in-haskell). The primary mechanism for gaining parallelism is via [explicit threading and locks](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html), though you may consider the use of STM instead of locks, or other parallel mechanisms (such as sparks, data parallelism or the Par monad).

Comment: When you initialize the runtime, you can pass it options including the number of capabilities to use: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html#using-own-main

Comment: just wanted to reiterate that I read a presentation you made and I found it very enlightening and this looks like it does answer the mail fully.  Thank you